# Is there any way using tidyverse R to change multiple column names by ascending series?

Tags: r, pipe, tidyverse

I'm trying to replace a for loop with some R `tidyverse` functions.
I have a series of columns with the names: OQ1, OQ2, OQ3.... OQ45
and I want to change their names to OQ_45_1, OQ_45_2... OQ_45_45

I've done it using for loop but is there anyway doing is using pipes %>%?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `rename_at` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% rename_at(vars(starts_with('OQ')), ~paste0('OQ_45_', seq_along(.)))
```

---

In base R, you can do it with

```
cols <- grep('^OQ', names(df))
names(df)[cols] <- paste0('OQ_45_', seq_along(cols))
```

Comment: if you have names already stored in vector, `n_vec <- paste0("OQ",1:20)
(t_vec <- str_replace(n_vec, pattern = "OQ", replacement = "OQ_45_"))`

Answer (score 3):

If all columns you need to alter start with 'QO' then you can rename_all using gsub.

```r
library(dplyr)

tibble(OQ1 = NA, OQ2 = NA, OQ3 = NA) %>% 
  rename_all( ~ gsub("^OQ", "OQ_45_", .x))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   OQ_45_1 OQ_45_2 OQ_45_3
#>   <lgl>   <lgl>   <lgl>  
#> 1 NA      NA      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score -1):

We can use `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      rename_at(vars(starts_with('OQ')), ~str_c('OQ_45_', seq_along(.)))
```